# How to use System.in.read() in java?

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream

I need to input and load some chars in a boolean 2-D array. If the char is `X`, mark the array element as `true`; else if the char is `.`, mark the array element as false.

Here is my design:

```
boolean[][] Array = new boolean[2][2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
   for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (System.in.read() == '.') {
            Array[i][j] = false;
        } else if (System.in.read() == 'X') {
            Array[i][j] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And, for example, if I type in `....` or `XXXX`, it does not produce the correct result. Also for other input the result is not correct.

So how to deal with this?

Comment: Have you started by reading the javadoc of `InputStream#read()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a character a second time in the loop if the first character is not a `'.'`.

You should only read one character per loop.  Save the character in a variable before your `if` statement, and then compare the variable to `'.'` and `'X'` in turn.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the `read()` function in each `if` statement. Call it one time and store it in a variable so you don't keep reading through the input. That could be one thing messing up your function. Another is how you are comparing `char`s with the `==` operator. Should use `char.equals` method for character comparison. Put a couple breakpoints in and see what values are being sent through to debug. Maybe try something like the following:

```
boolean[][] Array= new boolean[2][2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        Character input = (char)System.in.read();
        if (input.equals('.')) {
            Array[i][j] = false;
        } else if (input.equals('X')) {
            Array[i][j] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aha,but when I do this like you said,I got "char cannot be dereferenced" error.How can I solve it?

Comment: Try using Character instead of char. char is primitive. Character is the wrapper class that has methods on it. I changed my code above.